# Overload resolution with parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, overload-resolution

Say I have these two methods:

```cpp
// Overload 1
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void Foo(Args&&... args)
{
    // do things with T, args...
}

// Overload 2
template <typename T, typename... Args>
void Foo(std::function<void(T&)> && func, Args&&... args)
{
    // do things with func, T, args...
}
```

I'm trying to call it like so:

```cpp
Foo<MyClass>([](auto& my_class){
    // do things with my_class
});
```

I'm intending to call Overload 2. The problem is it actually resolves to Overload 1. I can get it working by making an explicit `std::function<void(MyClass&)> func` variable and passing that after removing the r-value on the `std::function`, but I'd like to try and get it working with the lambda. It also works with the lambda if I provide another parameter, but I won't have another parameter to give it.

Shouldn't the method with the `std::function` argument be more specialized? Why is it choosing the wrong overload? I've read the [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) rules, but am not seeing/understanding the reason for the behavior.

Given the fact it works with the explicit parameter, I'm assuming it has something to do with the implicit conversion from the lambda into the `std::function`, that conversion is ranked lower than just using `Args`, even if it is more specialized. Is there anything I can do to keep the lambda?

Comment: Your problem is a lambda expression does not result in a `std::funtion`.  It results in an unnamed class type that has an overloaded `operator ()`.

Comment: (1) is a closer match as it does not need to need to convert the lambda to a `std::function`.

Comment: As always, the problem is with taking a `std::function` parameter. Never do that. Just take the callable as whatever its type is.

Comment: `std::function` has such a misleading name, I guess `std::not_a_function` would have been less misleading ;) It is not the type to be used always when you want to pass a callable as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the method with the `std::function` argument be more specialized?

Yes, Overload 2 is more specialized than overload 1

> Why is it choosing the wrong overload?

Lambda is NOT a `std::function`, so first overload is a better match (as exact match).

> Is there anything I can do to keep the lambda?

Use regular template parameter instead of `std::function`:

```
template <typename T, typename F, typename... Args>
requires (std::invocable<F, T&>)
void Foo(F&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    // ...
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e89j9dTP4)

Comment: This looks good. Any way to mimic the `std::invocable` for c++17?

Comment: @anon Remove the `requires` line  and replace `void` with `std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, T&>>`